# Is Firebase-performance data is always visible after 12 hours?

Tags: firebase-performance

I followed the getting started with Firebase-performance for Android.
I could see the data in the dashboard after approx. 12 hours.

Is this delay always be the case? Or by the time the data can be visible even after 10 mins?

I tried 2 or 3 times in different days, but the delays is still huge, in hours.

Answer (score 1):

The delay of 12 hours seems to be on the higher end. Your data should be available on console within 12 hours.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android#check-thefirebase-console-for-performance-monitoring-results